# Doctrine - generate schema on not in bundle entity

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, entity

I have class

```
namespace Acme\Domain\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
   ...
}
```

Notice, tha this entity is not inside any bundle. Now, i want to generate schema, so i run:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:create
```

and i get:

```
No Metadata Classes to process.
```

How can I generate schema, using entity that is not in bundle?

One more thing, if i run:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entites Acme/Domain/Entity/User
```

It gives me error:

```
Class "Acme\Domain\Entity\User" is not a valid entity or mapped super class
```

It's imposible that this class is invalid, becouse i generate it using "doctrine:generate:entity", and move from bundle to Acme/Domain/Entity, and change only namespace. If entity is in bundle, all works fine. So how can i manage entity, outside the bundle?

Comment: This cookbook will help you http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/mapping_model_classes.html . Instead of `createXmlMappingDriver` use `createAnnotationMappingDriver`.

Comment: check the path of your class I reproduce your situation without error. I don't create entity by doctrine command, only by hand and the `doctrine:schema:create`command go fine